# How to link up the tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created 2 tables for phpMyAdmin. One of them is countries and the other is the users.

Countries table:

[image: Countries Table]

Users table:

[image: Users table]

I know how to create forms with HTML and PHP. I want my users to select a country, but the countries are in the different table and cannot be placed in the users table. Would I need to link it up by using the 'SQL' section on phpMyAdmin or is there a PHP code for it?

I haven't fully constructed the php form yet(just started!)

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <p>
    <label>UserName : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="usernamet" placeholder="Username" />
  </p>
  <input id="teamname" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Team Name" />
  </p>
  <select name="countries">
    <option value="England">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Spain">Saab</option>
    <option value="Turkey">Fiat</option>
    <option value="France">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    <label>E-Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label>
    <input id="password" type="email" name="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
  </p>
  <a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a>
  <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: This question is a little bit vague. Some coding from your current form would be appreciated. Essentially you would build the form via HTML but when you're ready for your country entry, you would loop though the results of a `SELECT *` from your countries table. Also you don't have a place to store the country in your users table. Where are you storing it at? One place to start would be adding a column to your users table to hold the country value. Try going back and edit this question. (Don't submit a new one.)

Comment: In response to your edit: Can you include the HTML/PHP for your current form as well?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, you can copy/paste the coding for the form. That'll make things a little bit easier. Also you still didn't answer where the details of the user's selected country is being stored. You currently have no field in the user's table to actually store that data. You will need to modify your users table to include some sort of `country` field with the type being `INT` and NOT some form of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... here goes my answer.

As I said, if you plan on asking for a user country, you HAVE to have a place to store it in that same table but if you plan on storing it in another table, that is fine too but you will need to change my single query insert into two query inserts. One to go into a table for your user information and the other to go into the table with the information that will hold the user ID# from the users table (or the `id` column) and the value from the form.

Original Table:

[image: Original Table from Question Provided]

New Table that I'm working with:
[image: Modified Table to Answer Question]

This form also includes error handling options like a blank form. If you want to validate email addresses and the like, search around for a function that will do just that and throw a handler in the verification section below. Also this code assumes you want the form to be processed on its self, that is the form and the code to process the form reside on the same script page. If you plan on doing anything besides, edit the `<form action=` and remove the `<?php ... ?>` coding from it. If you want to remove any of this, delete the lines of code related to that.

Also note that this script is using `mysqli_` functions and not `mysql_` functions as `mysql_` and related functions are considered deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP as of PHP 5.4 (I believe.)

If you don't want confirmation pages, you can edit the script to do just that for you. If you need anything else, edit your original question.

Your problem with the going through the countries list is resolved simply by performing a SELECT * query and then proceeding to loop through the results of that query and adding them to an array as I did. In this case, I used a `while()` loop to cycle through the results of the array returned from the `mysqli_query()` function and added the formatted results to an array that will eventually be outputted to the form.

```
<?php

//Define MySQLi connection information
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "stackoverflow", "", "stackoverflow");
    // mysqli_connect(SERVER_ADDR, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

if(isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0 ) {
    // If there is something to post, start this branch

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $teamname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['teamname']);
    $usercountry = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['countries']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    // Check to make sure we have a valid form. 
    // If you need more, follow the same pattern.

    if (empty($username) || empty($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "Username cannot be empty.";

    if (empty($email) || empty($_POST['email'])) $error[] = "Email Address cannot be empty.";

    if (empty($password) || empty($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Password cannot be blank.";

    if (empty($usercountry) || empty($_POST['countries'])) $error[] = "Please select a country from the drop down list.";

    if (!isset($error)) {
    // No errors? No problem. Insert the form data into the database.
    $user_insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, teamname, country, email, password, active, rank) VALUES ('" . $username . "' , '" .  $teamname . "', '" . $usercountry ."', '" . $email ."', PASSWORD('" . $password . "'), 1, 1)";

    mysqli_query($db, $user_insert);
    }

} ?>
<?php if (isset($error) || empty($_POST)) {

    // There was noting to post, so show the form to collect the information.

    // Retrieve the values from the countries table.

    $countries = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY countryName");

    $country_options = array();
    $country_options[] = array('value' => '', 'text' => '');
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($countries)) {
        $country_options[] = array('value' => $row['idCountry'], 'text' => $row['countryName']);
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>User Registration Form</title>
<!-- include your <style> CSS or imports here -->
<style>
.leftCell {
    width: 160px;
}
.error {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    color: #FF0000;
    padding: 10px;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
<div class="error">
<b>Please fix the following errors:</b>
<ul>
<?php foreach($error as $error_text) {
    echo "<li>" . $error_text . "</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- assuming you do not already have a script to input the data, I'm using this page to input the data -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">

  <!-- Let's create a table -->
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="leftCell">Desired User Name:</td>
      <td><input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo (isset($username) ? $username : ''); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="leftCell">Team Name:</td>
      <td><input id="teamname" type="text" name="teamname" placeholder="Team Name" value="<?php echo (isset($teamname) ? $teamname : ''); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50px;">User Country:</td>
      <td><select name="countries">
          <?php
        foreach($country_options as $country) {
            echo '<option value="' . $country['value'] . '" ' . ($country['value'] == $usercountry ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $country['text'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="leftCell">E-Mail:</td>
      <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="leftCell">Password:</td>
      <td><input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a class="btn" href="login.php">Login</a><br />
  <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } else { ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>User Registration - Success</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>The user was successfully registered!</h1>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```